# UK Visitor Visa application employment status help

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I am an Indian citizen planning to visit the UK along with my father as a tourist in February 2019. We would like to go sightseeing and visit various historic sites around the UK.

This is the first time either of us are applying for a UK Visit Visa. We are applying for a 6 month Standard Visit Visa.

I have a few issues with my application as I am 25 years old and have just finished my undergraduate education in Medicine in September 2018. I am giving my post-graduation entrance examinations presently and I am not presently employed anywhere.

I cannot prove that I am a student at present as I have recently passed out of college in September 2018. I do not have any savings of my own and I am dependent on my father who will be paying for all expenses for our trip to UK.

We are yet to apply for our Visas. In the application should I mention myself as unemployed because presently I am not employed and I cannot prove that I am a student. Will my visa application be rejected even though I am traveling with my father?

I can substantiate that I am dependent on my father from my bank account statement over that past years. My father has enough income and savings to pay for the trip for both of us and he will be submitting his bank statements and stock holding statements to substantiate the same.

Will it be sufficient to mention my present situation by mentioning that I am a Student who is preparing for my post-graduate entrance examinations and I am visiting the UK in the gap between my post-graduate exams and my admission into a post-graduate medical program? I can substantiate that I am appearing for my post-graduate examinations as I have admit cards for the examinations.

Or should I just apply as unemployed OR check both student and unemployed options? Will my visa be rejected because I am unemployed? I will not be able to find any time for a foreign trip once I start my post-graduate studies if I can't make it in February. So I am really worried about Visa rejection.

Comment: `Will my visa application be rejected even though I am traveling with my father?` Unemployed and not a student, you are looking at a possible rejection unfortunately. `Will it be sufficient to mention my present situation by mentioning that I am a Student who is preparing for my post-graduate entrance examinations and I am visiting the UK in the gap between my post-graduate exams and my admission into a post-graduate medical program? I can substantiate that I am appearing for my post-graduate examinations as I have admit cards for the examinations.` You can, still is not as strong as a student